# Revert default folder (Images)

Tags: 13.04, nautilus

I accidently moved /home/user/Desktop/Images folder to Desktop, and I thought that folder is just copy of original one so I deleted it, but it seems I moved it to Desktop and now I don't have Images folder. I created new Images folder manually but whenever I click on Images shortcut in left sidebar I get error 'Unable to find file' and it points to folder I droped on Desktop.

How to revert path to folder and icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by editing `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

Answer (score 1):

Edit Nautilus' bookmarks.
Oops my bad. Edited to reflect 13.04's location

~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks

Comment: I did, but now I have two bookmarks of folder Images. How do I delete the previous one. And my new bookmark is now located below Devices section.